# How to prevent the onAuthStateChange method from creating unnecessary listeners?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I have an application made in ReactJS + Vite that uses the Firebase login system.

Currently, all pages where the user needs to be logged in are being protected by the component called `ProtectedRoute.ts`:

```
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { ReactNode, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useUserDataContext } from '../../context/UserDataContext';

//Firebase Logic
import { auth } from '../../config/firebaseConfig';
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

interface ProtectedRouteProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

const ProtectedRoute = ({ children }: ProtectedRouteProps) => {

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [signed, setSigned] = useState(false);
  const {setUserData} = useUserDataContext();

  useEffect(() => {

    async function checkLogin(){
      onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {

        if(user){

          setUserData(user);

          setLoading(false);
          setSigned(true);
          return;
        }

        setLoading(false);
        setSigned(false);
      })
    }

    checkLogin();

  }, []);

  if(loading){
    return(<div></div>);
  }

  if(!signed){
    return <Navigate to='/login'></Navigate>
  }

  return children;

};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

As you can see, the component executes useEffect which in turn executes `onAuthStateChange()` every time a protected route is opened.

In this case, if the user refreshes the page, `onAuthStateChange()` is called. If the user goes to a new protected route, `onAuthStateChange()` is called again.

Could this cause a memory leak problem? If so, what would be the best way to fix this problem?

Comment: `onAuthStateChanged` returns an unsubscribe function that you need to also return from your useEffect so that it will stop the listener when the component unmounts.

Comment: Alternatively, don't use it inside a hook at all, and register just one observer for your entire app, then find. way to share its auth state changes anywhere it's needed.